# Why does VSCode Python always put two tabs instead of one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, save

In my VSCode settings, I have Tab Size set to 2 and in Prettier I have it set to 2 spaces as well. It works fine, whenever I go to the next line, it indents by 1 tab (2 spaces) and whenever I press tab it places a tab where my cursor was. But when I save my file, all of the single tabs for indenting turn into 2 tabs. Here is an image from after saving: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9epSQ.png). And yes, I am making a Discord Bot.

I saved my file and I expected it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLMEH.png)

Comment: I think you need to switch to Spaces. Click on `Tab Size: 2` in the bottom right corner and select "Indent with Spaces" and choose size 2

Comment: @Tranbi there isn't a button on the bottom right.

Comment: Don't you see a blue status bar? See https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UQ1x.png

Comment: Oh I found it. But I don't want to indent using spaces, I want to indent using tabs but when I save it indents with 2 tabs and that's annoying.

Comment: So... set size to 1?

Comment: But then it looks funny. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBPWh.png

Comment: Sorry I cannot reproduce the problem :-/

Comment: Check if the laguage is detected as python correctly at the bottom of vscode https://snipboard.io/CdZqLS.jpg

Comment: @RamsudharsanManoharan It is python. I have the Prettier extension and when I do Cmd+Shift+P and select Format Document With... it only shows Python. Prettier doesn't show up.

Comment: @AgentStrawberry Why would you want to see Prettier for python. It doesn't support python, its used for js. Pylance does the lintng for python. If it was working properly before and recently giving these issues, then try reverting back to a previous version of pylance from the extensions marketplace and that problem should be solved.

Comment: oh i didn't know that prettier didn't support python

Answer (score 2):

> I want to indent using tabs but when I save it indents with 2 tabs and that's annoying

[image]

1. Click the Select Indentation option in the lower right corner.

[image]

2. Choose **Indent Using Tabs**

[image]

3. Choose 2.

You can also change the settings by searching **tab size**:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: yeah umm i did that and it still doesn't work

Comment: @AgentStrawberry This is feasible for me, and it still works after multiple restarts. I'm sorry that your problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @AgentStrawberry Maybe the extensions you installed conflict with each other. It's a quick way to try to find those extensions or reinstall vscode

Comment: It still looks like this: see how there is 2 tabs (4 spaces) for each indent which is not what I want [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeOCU.png)

Comment: Okay I will try reinstalling

Comment: I reinstalled and it didn't help at all, I even deleted all of the vscode files.

Comment: Maybe you can temporarily turn off the formatting option when saving, but this is not a long-term method, because this setting works normally in my vscode, which is exactly what you need. Add the following line to your settings: `"editor.formatOnSave": false,`

Comment: These are my settings: https://pastebin.com/raw/X46RZm0z

Comment: @AgentStrawberry Unfortunately, I used your settings, and it still correctly shows that the tab is 2 spaces long. Have you tried uninstalled all extensions?

Comment: Yes, but the problem isn't the tab length. It's whenever I format my file, it replaces every single tab with 2 tabs, which means that [this](https://i.postimg.cc/dtQHQ2Tx/image.png) would turn into [this](https://i.postimg.cc/7hR2krzD/image.png)

Comment: Yes, so I still think the conflict is caused by the installation of other extensions.

Comment: My extensions are: Ayu, isort, Jupyter, Jupyter Cell Tags, Jupyter Keymap, Jupyter Notebook Renderers, Jupyter Slide Show, Material Icon Theme, Material Theme, Material Theme Icons, Pylance, and Python. I don't really use any Jupyter.

Comment: I have tried these extensions, and none of them will lead to the problem you mentioned. If you turn off formatOnSave and it still doesn't work, I'm sorry that I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Oh it works if I turn off formatOnSave obviously because when I save, it wont format. But it's just really confusing.