# Random Errors For No Reason

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason I am experiencing a lot of [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H80f.png)  regarding my indentation. I don't see anything wrong and I have re-typed the indentation multiple times. Maybe this has something to do with my other question [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502151/why-does-vscode-python-always-put-two-tabs-instead-of-one)

Here is the code where the error is:

```
@bot.command(description="See your balance or somebody else's balance.", aliases=['bal'])
async def balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
if member:
    if not currency['balance'][member.id]:
        currency['balance'][member.id] = 0
        save_data()
        ctx.message.reply(embed=discord.Embed(
            title=f"{member.name}'s Balance",
            description=f"{member.name}'s balance is `{currency['balance'][member.id]}`"
        ))
else:
    if not currency['balance'][ctx.author.id]:
        currency['balance'][ctx.author.id] = 0
    ctx.message.reply(embed=discord.Embed(
        title=f"Your Balance",
        description=f"Your balance is `{currency['balance'][ctx.author.id]}`"
    ))
```

Comment: We need a Minimum Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not a link to an image.

Comment: @QWERTYL So do I like put the piece of my code in there?

Comment: Move the entire code after if member by a tab.

Answer (score 0):

All the lines after the function definition need to be indented once more, since they have to belong to the function implementation. Like so:

```
@bot.command(description="See your balance or somebody else's balance.", aliases=['bal'])
async def balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member:
        if not currency['balance'][member.id]:
            currency['balance'][member.id] = 0
            save_data()
            ctx.message.reply(embed=discord.Embed(
                title=f"{member.name}'s Balance",
                description=f"{member.name}'s balance is `{currency['balance'][member.id]}`"
            ))
    else:
        if not currency['balance'][ctx.author.id]:
            currency['balance'][ctx.author.id] = 0
        ctx.message.reply(embed=discord.Embed(
            title=f"Your Balance",
            description=f"Your balance is `{currency['balance'][ctx.author.id]}`"
        ))
```

Comment: Oh it was like that I just had trouble pasting the code.